# Ransack - column equal 0 or null

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

Suppose I have a model `MyModel` with an attribute `star`. Which predicates in ransack should I use to get the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_models WHERE star = 0 OR star IS NULL;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing some tests and using the predicate `star_blank => 1` automatically does that.